# Using dropdownlist in a View where datasource is from database table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am writing code where a View is required that includes a dropdownlist enabling the user to select from list of values, these values are from a database table. The table is different from the data model used in the view.

The View allows only One data Model to be used. In my case I need at least 4 different tables to be used in different dropdownlist in the view.

I am using  Entity Framework database in ASP.NET Core 2.0 with C# code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ViewBag` to  pass your `dropdownlist` data-source as following e.g.
we get Types from DB and pass it to the view using `ViewBag` Value named `Types`
then bind it in our view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     ViewBag.Types = new SelectList(db.Types.ToList(), "Id", "Name");

     return View();
}


@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, (SelectList)ViewBag.Types, new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Comment: When using tins code I am getting an error of   NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Can you post your db model